# Can this kind of NP-Hard problem be approximated?

Tags: np-hard, approximation, decision-problem

Consider this kind of optimization problem:

(1) The problem aims to minimize a value. Let *n* denote this value.
(2) To determine whether *n* = 0 is a NP-Complete problem.

It is obvious that this kind of problem is at least NP-Hard. My question is, **can this kind of problem be approximated?** It seems that for any polynomial-time algorithm *A*, there exist some instances in which the optimal solution is 0 and the output of *A* is not 0. In this situation, the approximate ratio is infinite.

Comment: You'll have to slightly modify the notion of approximation in order to allow meaningful approximation algorithms. The definition of approximation is there to help us cope with NP-hard problems, so if it's not useful in a particular instance, it needs to be adjusted.

Comment: It is entirely possible to have a problem where n can be determined in polynomial time unless n = 0. And it is possible to have a problem where n = f() + g(), where f() is easy to calculate, g() is guaranteed 0 or 1, and determining whether g() = 0 is NP-complete.

Comment: "It is obvious that this kind of problem is at least NP-Hard": why ?

Comment: If the optimal value is 0, using a relative error is a nonsense.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62358/approximation-ratio-when-optimal-solution-is-0?rq=1 I think my question is the same as this problem. The answer argues that this kind of problem can not be approximated within a constant value.